# Controlling the Leaflet GeoJSON FeatureLayer selection color and selection border color?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, leaflet

The following options will render the fill and border color for leaflet GeoJSON layers.

```
  /**
   * Creates all the GeoJSON layers and adds
   * event handlers.
   */
  private createGeoJsonLayer(geodata: any, map: L.Map): L.GeoJSON<any> {
    const layers: L.GeoJSON<any> = L.geoJSON(geodata as any, {
      style: {
        weight: 2,
        color: 'orange',
        opacity: 0.8,
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
      },
      onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
        this.onEachFeature(feature, layer);
      },
    });
```

This is an Angular demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xuqt3y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fleaflet-demo.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fleaflet-demo.component.css

How do we set the selection fill and border color.

Currently the selection has a blue fill with a yellow border.  How would we set these values and does leaflet have documentation for these options?

Answer (score 0):

OK - The selection colors are set in the event handling functions.  So the below will set the border color to `pink` and the `fillColor` to green when the feature is hovered over and clicked.

```
  private onMouseOver(featureLayer) {
    if (featureLayer) {
      featureLayer.setStyle({
        weight: '2', //border width
        color: 'pink', //border color
        fillColor: 'green',
      });

      if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera12 && !L.Browser.edge) {
        featureLayer.bringToFront();
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's a demo.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8yy5v8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fleaflet-demo.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fleaflet-demo.component.css